# Как перевести кодировку с cp1251 в utf8 на node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер

Пытаюсь парсить сайт, страница находится в кодировке cp1251, при выводе у меня появляются ромбики с вопросильтельными знаками внутри, пробовал через iconv-lite но результат тот же, пытался получить данные как через http и request. Подскажите как можно еще попробовать

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил с помощь библиотеки superagent-charset